# Static Resource in VF : Failed to load resource

Tags: visualforce, static-resources, bootstrap

I am trying to reference bootstrap in my VF.

I have uploaded the boostrap distribution archive file as a Static resource. (bstrap)[image]

.
The folder structure is as follows

[image]

I need to reference two files (one is bootstrap.min.css and another is bootstrap.min.js)

I am using the following markup in my VF

```
<apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.bstrap, 'bstrap/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist.zip/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css')}"/>
<apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.jq}"/>
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.bstrap, 'bstrap/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist.zip/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js')}"/>
```

The jQuery file is loaded without any issues but the bootstrap files are not getting loaded at all.

I observed in the Chrome Console shown below.
[image]

Can someone tell me what could be the issue ?

Comment: I think  this should work for you .<apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.bstrap, 'bstrap/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css')}"/>

Comment: I figured it out....:) I need to use something like this <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.bstrap, '/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css')}"/>
<apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.jq}"/>
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.bstrap, '/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js')}"/>